# How to add more regions for the geFunctions() function in Angularfirebase application?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

Freibase does not give asia-southeast1 region in Freibase Extension, where most of my functions are. asia-southeast2 is nearest. I tried adding it to my Angular main.ts bootstrap to access both. I tried constructing it as an array ['asia-southeast1', 'asia-southeast2'] but it only accepts string parameters.

```
function bootstrap() {
  bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
      provideRouter(MAIN_ROUTES),
      importProvidersFrom(
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
        provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
        provideAuth(() => {
          const auth = getAuth();
          if (environment.useEmulators) {
            connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099', {
              disableWarnings: true, // Set to true to disable the warning in the console
            });
          }
          return auth;
        }),
        provideDatabase(() => getDatabase()),
        provideFirestore(() => {
          const firestore = getFirestore();
          if (environment.useEmulators) {
            connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
          }
          return firestore;
        }),
        
        // HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD 'asia-southeast2'
        provideFunctions(() => getFunctions(getApp(), 'asia-southeast1')),
        // BELOW IS MY ATTEMPT 
        // provideFunctions(() => getFunctions(getApp(), ['asia-southeast1', 'asia-southeast2'])),
        provideMessaging(() => getMessaging()),
        providePerformance(() => getPerformance()),
        provideRemoteConfig(() => getRemoteConfig()),
        provideStorage(() => {
          const storage = getStorage();
          if (environment.useEmulators) {
            connectStorageEmulator(storage, 'localhost', 9199);
          }
          return storage;
        }),
        ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
          enabled: environment.production,
          // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the app is stable
          // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
          registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000',
        })
      ),
      ScreenTrackingService,
      UserTrackingService,
    ],
  }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```